# how to select all data from table but drop value if it is equals to data of other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How to write SQL statement for selecting records form a table which have no corresponding records in the second table.

Example: there are two tables `a` and `b`.

```
a (id, first, second, third)
b (id, whatever)
```

I should select all data from table `a`, without the records where `a.id = b.id`. That record should not be selected.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Feel free to upvote the aswers you find helpful, or even accept the one which solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Whith an EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.id=a.id)
```

Whithout subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id=a.id
WHERE b.id is null
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: The second version is not equivalent.  First, you want to say `SELECT a.*`.  Second, there can be multiple rows in b with the same id, resulting in duplicate rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff True. Added `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from a where a.id not in (select distinct id from b)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use by LEFT JOIN in the combination with the WHERE clause to filter out the records. And I have an example below:

```
SELECT 
      a.*
FROM 
    a
LEFT JOIN 
         b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE 
     b.id IS NULL;
```